# When Multiplication : IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, android, python-2.7, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

When i am trying to multiplication with two number getting below error in jupyter.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.executing_eagerly()

x = tf.constant(2)
y = tf.constant(3)
multi = x*y
with tf.Session() as sess:
print(sess.run(multi))

## error 

File "<ipython-input-35-755ab78de6c6>", line 5
    print(sess.run(multi))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

[please help me to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELe43.png)

Comment: don't link image, copy the code in your question and format it as code

Comment: @Ben2209 thanks for replay, i have put the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution and Special Thanks To @Ben2209

```
tf.__version__

tf.executing_eagerly()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant(2)
    b = tf.constant(5)
    c = a*b
    print(sess.run(c))

** Output **
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You must indent the last line (starting with print).

Comment: thank for replay, can you please write the code? bcz i don't know about indent.

Comment: Indentation is a fundamental concept of python. You should learn the basics. You can find a list of resources for beginners here https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Comment: @VishalBhimani Did you try using an English dictionary, in order to understand what the word "indent" means?